# Failed to create native media resource while using vlcj to create a media player

Tags: java, vlcj

I am building a media player using vlcj? When i run the code the gui open fine but the video dosen't play.

// Checking for the native path

```
    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), NATIVE_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH);
    System.out.println(LibVlc.INSTANCE.libvlc_get_version());
    }

    // Swing part
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Tutorial(args);
        }
    });



        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void playing(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        frame.setTitle(String.format(
                            "My First Media Player - %s",
                              mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().getMediaMeta().getTitle()
                        ));
                    }
                });
            }

            public void finished(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        closeWindow();
                    }
                });
            }


            public void error(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                            frame,
                            "Failed to play media",
                            "Error",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
                        );
                        closeWindow();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(args[0]);
    }
```

I get the following error.

9 [main] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info - vlcj: 3.7.0
9 [main] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info - java: 1.8.0_31 Oracle Corporation
9 [main] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info - java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31
9 [main] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info - os: Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64
932 [main] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.discovery.NativeDiscovery - Discovery found libvlc at 'C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC'
true
2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax)

1367 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlcFactory - vlc: 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax), changeset 2.2.1-0-ga425c42

1367 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlcFactory - libvlc: C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\libvlc.dll

2061 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.DefaultMediaPlayer - Failed to create native media resource for 'SimpleMedia[mrl=C:/Users/venkatneehar/Downloads/1.mpg,mediaOptions=[Ljava.lang.String;@a420335]'

Answer (score 1):

Your MRL (the filename) is using forward slashes on Windows.

Forward slashes are accepted on Windows by Java for reasons of cross-platform compatibility, but it will not work when passing the filename to VLC which uses a native function call to open the file.

So, use a 'proper' Windows filename with backslashes and it will work.

Comment: It worked fine after I've changed the path to use backward slash (\)